# how to access end user context on resource server

Tags: api, security, oauth, openid

I have an API management implementation as follows.

End User <--> Web App <--> API Server Gateway <--> API Resource Server

I use OAuth grant_type=code to authenticate the user credentials and then access API Resource using the tokens.

As API Provider (resource developer), I need to access the end user credentials (or atleast the context) to know who is initiating the request and provide the response customised for the user.

is it possible ? if yes, does that vioalate the OpenID / OAtuh standards ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible and no - you won't be violating the OAuth standards. Reason: Validation of tokens (exchange of information between the authorization server and the resource server is out of the scope of OAuth spec).

Quoting from [OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-introspection-08)

> Since OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] does not define a protocol for the resource
> server to learn meta-information about a token that is has received
> from an authorization server, several different approaches have been
> developed to bridge this gap.

Two most important entities that the authorization server would be returning as a result of introspection are the **user-identifier** and the **approved scopes** (via the token presented).

The introspection could be done in several ways:

- The Google Way: [Validate Token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent?hl=es#validatetoken)
- JWT - JWT based Access Tokens have scope and user information available with them, so it may not be necessary to reach out to the authorization server for vertification*.
- etc.

Comment: Thanks. Please can you point me to any sample for JWT interaction with API ?

Comment: Try these: [Server](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server) and [Sample Application](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/simple-web-app). It's very straightforward to setup the two applications. You just need to add both the wars to tomcat and start.